# Increment/decrement count value in a table depending on insert/delete of a specific column value of another table using triggers in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers, sql-update

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ujxy.png)

The above screenshot shows two tables `employee` and `department` where employee contains details of employees and department contains information on the department.

Upon insert or delete in the `employee` table, depending on the `dno` value, an increment/decrement has to be done in `dcount` of the `department` table.

**Goal** is to automate the count of employees in department upon insertion and deletion in employee table.

I tried using function which increments/decrements the value using if and elsif for operation 'INSERT' and 'DELETE', but all that does is increment all the values in dcount by 1.

It does not increase/decrease a particular department `dcount` value respective to inserted or deleted `dno` value from employee table.

Need some help and guidance.

Thank you.

Gruheeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tables for test

```
create table employee (fname text, dno integer);
create table department (dname text, dnumber integer, dcount integer default 0);

insert into department (dname,dnumber) values ('Research',5),('Administration',4),('Headquarters',1);
```

i created two functions which’s  increment and decrement counters in department table and then added them to triggers on delete and insert

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION increment_c() RETURNS trigger AS $increment_c$
    BEGIN
        update department set dcount=dcount+1 where dnumber=NEW.dno;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$increment_c$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE or replace FUNCTION decrement_c() RETURNS trigger AS $decrement_c$
    BEGIN
        update department set dcount=dcount-1 where dnumber=OLD.dno;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$decrement_c$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create TRIGGER tr_insert AFTER insert on employee for each row execute procedure increment_c();
create TRIGGER tr_delete AFTER delete on employee for each row execute procedure decrement_c();
```

test and result **insert**

```
insert into employee values ('James',1),('Jhon',5),('Frenklin',5);
INSERT 0 3
postgres=# select * from department;
     dname      | dnumber | dcount
----------------+---------+--------
 Administration |       4 |      0
 Headquarters   |       1 |      1
 Research       |       5 |      2
```

and **delete**

```
delete from employee where fname='Jhon';
DELETE 1
postgres=# select * from department;
     dname      | dnumber | dcount
----------------+---------+--------
 Administration |       4 |      0
 Headquarters   |       1 |      1
 Research       |       5 |      1
```